# EXIM4 configuration not working for only 1 machine.

Tags: email, exim

Here is the deal.

We have a printer and all our machines have debian in our office. I've configured the printer to send mails to the server (pc00) via its IP (which is static). I created a hubbed_hosts file that tells exim each machine, which IP it has. So my own personal mahcine is ariela@pc01 since I have pc01 and my username is ariela. This should get received in the mbox file. This works in every other machine except mine.

If I print the exim log I get:

```
ariela@pc01 R=hubbed_hosts T=remote_smtp defer (-44): SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<ariela@pc01>: host 192.168.2.101 [192.168.2.101]: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
```

It seems as if the problem is in my client machine, howerver I've runned the exim4-config with dpkg-reconfigure for my machine and It is the exact same things as the others that do work. I'm clueless.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a name resolution problem. Which would explain the different behaviour despite the identical exim config files.

Comment: The IP shown is correct. It is supposed to be 192.168.2.1. How can I check it what you suggest?